# How do you update attributes in an instance method in a rails model without using different variable names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to update attributes in an instance method in rails without being forced to change the parameters being passed in so that I can advantage of rails automatic attributes. Here is an example.

Ideal:

```
status = "some_new_status"
person.update(status)

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update(status)
    self.status = status
  end
end
```

What I have to do now:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update(new_status)
    self.status = new_status
    self.save
  end
end
```

I understand in this example it doesn't much matter. But when I have complicated update methods, it would be a lot cleaner if I could eliminate some of that code.

Comment: why did you rollback the presentation of your question?

Comment: that's a good question; i wanted to see if it would wipe out the question completely / revert it to nothing.

Answer (score 20):

You should use builtin Rails methods:

```
@person.update_attribute(:status, "Some Value") #no callback triggered nor validation

@person.update_attributes(:status => "Some Value") #can pass multiple values
```

Or to keep your short syntax

```
def update(status)
  update_attribute(:status, status)
end
```

[Update_attribute doc.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attribute)

[Update_attributes doc.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attributes)

Comment: You need to correct it a bit. When you're using update_attributes method, you should write it like this: :status => 'active'

Comment: I feel that as a new user, he might not be aware of such feature as "accepted answer" ;)

Comment: it turns out you can't use the update method as an instance method because it is a private method somewhere else in the object hierarchy.

Comment: I often use this. Did you really try?

Comment: Isn't the suggestion to write an instance method for `update` causing a conflict with Rails build in `update` methoid?